# What should I do if wire gauge is too large to fit into a screw terminal?

Tags: electrical, wiring

First time poster here. I am working on a robot controller that requires mains power. I was provided 10AWG wire (the unit recommends 14-10AWG, and this is National Electric Code FTR).

I took out the screw on the lines terminal and wrapped the copper wire around it, but no matter how I align it (particularly if i want a good solid safe contact), it begins to fray and although it stays put (and i powered it on just to make sure the controller was working), I am not comfortable having it frayed.

Any recommendations on what I could do? Should I just request a lower gauge wire, or one of my colleagues recommended a screwdown clamp, although space is an issue since it's inside the controller box.

Suggestions?

Comment: A photo might be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using #10 stranded under a screw using a crimp terminal will be the easiest and safest connection.

For that size and application you'd want to use a yellow fork terminal.

Here is a good tutorial: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/working-with-wire/how-to-crimp-an-electrical-connector